# Receive arrays of arrays of ... in D function?

Tags: arrays, d

Don't know if is possible, I want receive maybe `data[n]` or `data[n][n][n]`. In C could be (correct me if wrong):

```
void save_data(void* arr, int n, int dimensions)
{
    // do ugly things
}
```

But must exist a more elegant way in D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One alternative besides using C style pointer arithmetics is to template `safe_data`, i.e. do something like this:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

void safe_data(T)(in T arr) {
    static if(isArray!T) {
        writeln("Length ", arr.length); // do some ugly stuff for whole array
        foreach(e; arr) safe_data(e);   // recursively go deeper
    } else {
        writeln("Element ", arr);       // do more ugly stuff on individual elements
    }
}

void main() {
    writeln("A");
    int[3] A = [1,2,3];
    safe_data(A);
    writeln("B");
    int[3][2] B = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
    safe_data(B);
}
```

Depending on what you want to do with the data, you might want to use `ref` instead on `in`. BTW, if you prefer, you can move the `static if` outside of the function which makes for cleaner code sometimes:

```
// handle arrays
void safe_data(T)(in T arr) if(isArray!T) {
        writeln("Length ", arr.length); // do some ugly stuff for whole array
        foreach(e; arr) safe_data(e);   // recursively go deeper
}

// handle array elements
void safe_data(T)(in T e) if(!isArray!T) {
        writeln("Element ", e);         // do more ugly stuff on individual elements
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I don't understand well templates but your example is very elucidatory.

Comment: @Pedro: you are welcome. If you want to serialize data, Orange (http://www.dsource.org/projects/orange) might be worth a look.